# Upgrade SharePoint app fails

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, app

When I try to upgrade a SharePoint 2013 app with an integrated workflow (add-in created in Visual Studio) it fails.

> There was a problem accessing the file system on the server.
>   Details: Cannot complete this action. Please try again.

*Until* I deleted al the tasks from the Workflow Task List (related to that workflow).

Comment: are these workflow tasks created with app only permission.

Comment: How do I check this?
It's just the "SingleTask" building block that I dragged to the workflow...